# How to register ssh key in vagrant using ansible for newly created user?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

Currently I am using vagrant box and ansible . My  local config network is config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10".

I added a user in vagrant box by using playbook-ansible:

```
  hosts: all
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    authorized_key: user=root
                    key="{{ lookup('file','/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
                    path=/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/root
                    manage_dir=no
```

When I did `vagrant ssh` I could see the 'root' user in home directory and authorized key in /etc/ssh/authorized/toot, but when I do `root@192.168.33.10`

> Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
>
> root@192.168.33.10's password:

It is asking for password. I tries everything to login without password(ssh key based authentication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe, the playbook did the job.
Check the ssh settings. Without knowing which box you use, that is hard to tell. 
For example: on ubuntu the default setting in the sshd_config file for PasswordAuthentication is yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are adding the key for root user but you mentioning it in the wrong dest directory:

```
hosts: all
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: Add Authorized Key for ROOT
      authorized_key: user={{ username }} 
                      key="{{ lookup('file','~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}" 
                      state=present
```

Change key="{{ lookup('file','~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}" to also like this, if it cannot find the key with relative path:

```
key="{{ lookup('file','/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Uncomment this from /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

if still, facing a problem, change this line also like this:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: here root as a reference of username , it could be anything. I just changed sshd_config file of VM box and it works. Thanx anyway

Comment: I just make it easy to your situation, can you please specify that which option you have changed in the sshd_config?

Comment: In virtual box , sshd_config file  PasswordAuthentication is no and uncomment this lineAuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys , but now I changes my ansible file  and it is working too

Comment: I have added your comment inside the answer so that it will help others as well. thanks